# Convert natural exponent, $e^{c\cdot x}$, into the form $a^{x}$

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

How does one convert a natural exponent written as $e^{c\cdot x}$ into the form $a^{x}$ ?

Comment: Hint: $x^{ab} = (x^a)^b$

Comment: Hard to tell what is being asked

Comment: If $a$ is specified ahead of time, you can’t in general; otherwise just note that $e^{cx}=(e^c)^x$ and let $a=e^c$.

Comment: What @Victor said.

Comment: This question strikes me as slightly counterproductive. I don't see this as a question more than I see it as a statement that one is not aware of how exponentiation works.

Comment: I don't think it's hard to tell what is being asked.  @user22144 : _Every_ question legitimately posted here is a statement that one is not aware of its answer.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Well put. I concede.

Answer (score 3):

Since you can put $e^c=a$, you have that

$$e^{c \cdot x} = (e^c)^x=a^x$$

If you have that $a$ is some other number you can choose $c=\log a$ to get $e^c = a$